# python-user-agents library is not working

Tags: python, browser, user-agent

I am trying to use the [python-user-agents](https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents/blob/master/user_agents/parsers.py). I keep running into a number of bugs within the library itself.

First it referred to a `from ua_parser import user_agent_parser` that it never defined. So after banging my head, I looked online to see what that might be and found that `ua_parser` is yet another library that this project was using. So I downloaded `ua_parser`. But now I am getting an error that

```
TypeError: parse_device() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'
```

Sure enough, `ua_parser` has a model variable that the python-user-agents library is not expecting. Has anyone done a better job with this library? Whoever wrote it clearly did a terrible job. But it seems to be the only thing out there that I could find. Any help fixing it to work well? I am looking to use it so to identify if a browser's device is mobile or touchable or a tablet as in: `user_agent.is_mobile` or `user_agent.is_touch_capable` or `user_agent.is_tablet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you look at the readme from the github link it tells you what to install and how to use the lib:

You need pyyaml and ua-parser:

```
pip install pyyaml ua-parser user-agents
```

A working example:

```
In [1]: from user_agents import parse

In [2]: ua_string = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3'

In [3]: user_agent = parse(ua_string)

In [4]: user_agent.is_mobile
Out[4]: True

In [5]: user_agent.is_touch_capable 
Out[5]: True

In [6]: user_agent.is_tablet
Out[6]: False
```

Comment: So the part about doing it manually is not accurate. I have never used pip so since the person said I could do it manually by copying the git files, I copied the git file.

Comment: If you remove the old package and reinstall as above you should have no problems. Some pip installs will install the dependencies also, that must not be the case with this package.

Comment: no worries, I tested it out using various inputs and it worked well.

Comment: I don't mean to bother you too much. But when I do it in the terminal it works. But when I do it inside my python project I get the error `ImportError: No module named user_agents`. Do you know how I might fix this?

Comment: you are not using a different interpreter or python version in your project?

Comment: That's possible. I don't know enough to know. I am on OSX mavericks. The terminal python is `Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)` and the one in my app.yaml is `runtime: python27`. Other than that I don't know where my project is pulling python from. Is there a way to specify which python to install pip and user_agents for?

Comment: what does `which -a python` from bash output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67586/discussion-between-katedral-pillon-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: it prints /usr/bin/python

Comment: Nice to see a real expert is helping. +1. I look forward to the resolution.

Comment: After 1 hour, I realized it wasn't working because my script name was ```ua_parser``` which was colliding with the library's name. Don't be me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the new version of ua-parser is incompatible with this so you have to  install ua-parser==0.3.6